# Mysql-python not installed with bitnami django stack? "Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb"

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, bitnami

So I installed Bitnami Django stack, hoping as proclaimed 'ready-to-run' versions of python and mysql. However, I can't get python to syncdb: "Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb"

I thought the Bitnami package would already install everything necessary in Windows to make mysql and Python work together? Is this not true?

I don't want to have to deal with installing mysql-python components as that can be frustrating to get working alone as I have tried before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install MySQL for python as Django needs this to do the connecting, once you have the package installed you shouldn't need to configure it though as Django just needs to import from it.

Edit: from your comments there is a setuptools bundled but it has been replaced by the package distribute, install this python package and you should have access to easy_install which makes it really easy to get new packages. Assuming you've added PYTHONPATH/scripts to your environment variables, you can call easy_install mysql_python

Comment: I run python setup.py build for mysql-python library. I get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Extensi
ImportError: No module named setuptools              ------ this is why I wanted bitnami to do it for me. I don't know why everything is not packaged in bitnami or setuptools is not packaged in python already.

Comment: Ok I used ez_setup.py and that got rid of the first error. But now I can't find SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.0---there is no such registry key, and so setup.py isn't working. I can't find where mysql registry keys are.

Comment: what version of mysql-python did you get and what version of python are you running?

Comment: I grabbed MySQL-python-1.2.3. and the latest BitNami DjangoStack. I had installed Python 2.7 before I installed Bitnami, but I think BitNami brings in Python 2.6 too, but in installation I said to use my own python.

Comment: Just ran through the installer and it didn't give the option to use own installation of python, so you've probably got two versions of python installed on your computer now, and you are calling syncdb from the non bitnami one.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure what to do at the moment, other than say, uninstall python, and then uninstall bitnami then reinstall bitnami.

Answer (score 0):

BitNami DjangoStack already includes the mysql-python components  components. I guess you selected MySQL as the database when installing the BitNami Stack, right? (it also includes PostgreSQL and SQLite). Do you receive the error at installation time? Or later working with your Django project?

In which platform are you using the BitNami DjangoStack?

Answer (score 0):

So I got this error after installing Bitnami Django stack on Windows Vista.  Turns out that I had all components installed, but `easy_install mysql_python` didn't unwrap the entire package...  ?
I inst... uninst... inst... uninst multiple times, but no combination (using mysql for the startup Project) made any difference.

In the end, I simply renamed the egg file (in this case MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg) file to .zip and extracted the missing parts into a directory on my PYTHONPATH and everything worked like a charm.